# How to debug library conflicts?

Tags: arduino

I'm running through the Elegoo lessons, and have successfully done both the numeric keypad and the IR remote lessons. The lesson code and PDF are at http://www.elegoo.com/tutorial/Elegoo%20The%20Most%20Complete%20Starter%20Kit%20for%20UNO%20V1.0.17.8.3.zip in case anybody wants to look.

I am now trying to create my own project which uses **both** IR and keypad inputs. I've merged the code, adjusted the pin numbers, included both libraries (Keypad and IRemote) and the code basically works. Specifically, the keypad works correctly, and the IR remote does something. So I know that the wiring is OK and the input devices are both working.

The problem I have is that any press on the IR remote comes up as `REPEAT` rather than the decoded key value. If I comment out the Keypad code, the IR remote works correctly. So, it seems that the Keypad library is somehow conflicting with the IRemote library.

I'm not asking anybody to go debugging the libraries for me (but if you want to - don't let me stop you). Rather I'm looking for pointers on the sorts of conflicts that can arise so i can do some debugging myself.

My loop code is:

```
void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey(); // IF I COMMENT OUT THIS LINE, IR WORKS OK
  // do something with key
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    // have we received an IR signal?
    translateIR();
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
  }
}

void translateIR() {
  // takes action based on IR code received
  // describing Remote IR codes
  switch(results.value) {
    case 0xFFA25D: Serial.println("POWER"); break;
    case 0xFFE21D: Serial.println("FUNC/STOP"); break;
    case 0xFF629D: Serial.println("VOL+"); break;
    case 0xFF22DD: Serial.println("FAST BACK"); break;
    case 0xFF02FD: Serial.println("PAUSE");    break;
    case 0xFFC23D: Serial.println("FAST FORWARD"); break;
    case 0xFFE01F: Serial.println("DOWN"); break;
    case 0xFFA857: Serial.println("VOL-"); break;
    case 0xFF906F: Serial.println("UP"); break;
    case 0xFF9867: Serial.println("EQ"); break;
    case 0xFFB04F: Serial.println("ST/REPT"); break;
    case 0xFF6897: Serial.println("0"); break;
    case 0xFF30CF: Serial.println("1"); break;
    case 0xFF18E7: Serial.println("2"); break;
    case 0xFF7A85: Serial.println("3"); break;
    case 0xFF10EF: Serial.println("4"); break;
    case 0xFF38C7: Serial.println("5"); break;
    case 0xFF5AA5: Serial.println("6"); break;
    case 0xFF42BD: Serial.println("7"); break;
    case 0xFF4AB5: Serial.println("8"); break;
    case 0xFF52AD: Serial.println("9"); break;
    case 0xFFFFFFFF: Serial.println(" REPEAT");break;  
    default: 
      Serial.println(" other button   ");
  }// End Case
  delay(500); // Do not get immediate repeat
} //END translateIR
```

Comment: I also comment out the line below that references key. What I was trying to say is that it is the keypad.getKey() that is causing the damage. I'll simplify the snippet to make it clearer

Comment: How would you know what the IR is doing?  Nothing in that code ever even looks at the code you received. Or is there more to this code that you didn't post?  Post it all if you want help figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: translateIR() displays the code received. I've now pasted it into the question

Comment: I guess the "post all of it" was just lost on you.  Either that or you just ignored me.  Either way, I guess I can't help you since you can't follow basic directions.  Good luck.

Comment: @Delta_G read the question. I am looking for pointers from experienced Arduino developers on the sorts of conflicts that can arise between libraries. If you really want to see the code, including the libraries, it's all in the ZIP file which you are welcome to download.

Comment: Yes, but for that general question the only answer is, "Look at the code and see if both libraries try to use any of the same resources or if either one does something that affects the other."  There's not really a general answer for how to do that.  You could get help fixing the code you have if that was what you wanted, but you'd have to post something complete.  The libraries are fairly common, but your variable definitions and setup are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm hitting known issue https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/issues/251